# Duration in traffic from android app

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

I am trying to get response from Google Directions API including `duration_in_traffic`. In documentation to response there are conditions for this value to be included, one of them is

> The request includes a valid Google Maps API for Work client and
>   signature parameter.

If I understand google APIs correctly, the [client+signature](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices/auth) is authentication scheme used in server-server (web-service) calls and it would be bad idea to include cryptographic key into mobile app to generate signature.

So, how to get `duration_in_traffic` in response from request generated from android app? Can I somehow make it work by using `Key for Android applications` form Google Developer console? Assuming I need "Google Maps API for Work", how can I enable it for my Google developer console account?

Comment: `duration_in_traffic` is not available for Android, it's part of the Google Map Web APIs, specifically [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/). Either call the web api through [HTTP requests within android](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html) or implement some third party libraries (like [this one](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-GoogleDirectionAndPlaceLibrary)). The Android key you're talking about is for accessing the API. Google Maps for Work is a paid service, which is completely different.

Comment: Yes, I know it is not part of Maps library, I am using it via HTTP request. But I am still not sure about authentication. Or you are not suppose to use it from client app at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definite answer from Google Maps for Work support:

> The duration in traffic is currently only available to authenticated
>   Maps for Work requests, those that include a client ID and signature. 
>   Unfortunately it is not possible to have this returned when requesting
>   directions in any other way.  Additionally it is not possible to place
>   requests to any of the Web Services using an Android or iOS key. 
>   These only function with the respective mobile APIs.
>
> If you want to place requests for directions from a mobile device the
>   advisable way to achieve this is to proxy your request via one of your
>   own servers.  Essentially the device sends the request to the server
>   (with some form of authentication if you so desire) and the server
>   then sends the Maps for Work request to us.  Once it receives the
>   response this is sent back to the mobile device.  By doing it this way
>   you do not expose your crypto key in order to mke the requests.

**TL;DR:** No way to use from android app, you must use your server as proxy and implement own authentication (and rate limiting, throttling, etc.) to mind your quotas